# Encoding With HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a webpage that contains special characters such as "é". The problem is that these characters are appearing differently in the final output of my code. Here is an example:

"Réalisations" becomes "RÃ©alisations"

I am parsing the document in a very basic way; first I send an HttpWebRequest, get the response, then load the HtmlDocument from this response, like so:

```
HtmlDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

The first thing I checked was the encoding, but it is correctly being set to UTF-8. Does anyone know what could cause such a thing?

Some additional info:

When I copy the HtmlDocument's html (HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml) into a .txt file, it renders incorrectly at first, but when I close and open the .txt file it renders correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem might be in where you get HtmlDocument content at first step. Have you checked what is returning from response.GetResponseStream()?

Comment: Put it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first get the page content, the encoding might be wrong and it has nothing to do with HTMLAgilityPack. It will be solved when you set encoding at webrequest.